# Когда использовать маркерные интерфейсы, а когда маркерные аннотации?

Tags: java

Когда использовать маркерные интерфейсы, а когда маркерные аннотации? Являются ли упомянутые элементы взаимозаменяемыми?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Интерфейсы определяют тип.**

Интерфейс отмечает объект реализующий какой-либо тип. А значит исключает ошибки на этапе компиляции.

Пример:

```
interface MyMark {}

class MarkedClazz implements MyMark {}
class NonMarkedClazz {}

class Test {
  public static void test(MyMark markedObject) {
     // do somthing.
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) { 
     MarkedClazz marked = new MarkedClazz();
     NonMarkedClazz nonMarked = new NonMarkedClazz();
     test(marked);
     //test(nonMarked); // Ошибка компиляции.
  }
}
```

**2. Интерфейс определяет тип для наследников класса**

Если указать, что класс имплементирует интерфейс, то и все его наследники будут его имплементировать. Нельзя разимплементировать интерфейс у наследников. Здесь аннотации имеют преимущество, однако проверка наличия маркера переносится на время исполнения, что чревато ошибками.

Пример:

```
interface MyMark {}

@Target(value = ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {}

@MyAnnotation 
class Parent implements MyMark {}
class Heir extends Parent {}
class Test {
  public static void test(MyMark markedObject) {
    // do somthing.
  }

  public static void testAnno(Object object) {
      if(!object.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class)) { 
         throw new RuntimeException("object is not annotated by MyAnnotation")
      }
      // do something
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Parent parent = new Parent();
    Heir heir = new Heir();
    test(parent);
    test(heir); // ошибок нет
    testAnno(parent);
    testAnno(heir); // ошибка времени исполнения.
  }
}
```

**Итог:**

Если вам нужно пометить классы с тем, чтобы определять могут ли методы принимать объекты этих классов, то удобнее применять интерфейсы, так как ошибка выявится на этапе компиляции.

Если вам требуется анализировать метаданные класса, то в этом случае аннотации гораздо более гибкие и дают больше возможностей, особенно если учесть что аннотации могут иметь параметры. Однако анализ аннотаций переносится на время исполнения.

Следует отметить, что механизм аннотаций шире, чем просто пометка классов, так как позволяет аннотировать методы, поля, параметры, конструкторы, локальные переменные и пакеты. Но эта тема достаточно обширная и выходит за рамки вопроса.